# How to figure out if the Date string contains time offset added already in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, date, utc, datetimeoffset

Consider this date string:

```
"2012-08-20T15:00:00-07:00"
```

It has time offset added as `"-07:00"`
How can I find out it has this offset added?
I know I can do it with regular expressions.
But is there any other easier way?

Or does any one have the regex for it?

Answer (score 1):

> I know I can do it with regular expressions, but is there any other easier way?

I don't think so, regexes are the simplest pattern matchers available.

> does any one have the regex for it?

I think this should do it:

```
/[+-]\d\d:\d\d$/.test(datestring)
```

If you want to parse it, use

```
var match = /([+-]?\d\d):(\d\d)$/.exec(datestring);
if (match)
    return parseInt(match[1], 10)*60 + parseInt(match[2], 10)*(match[1].charAt(0)=="-"?-1:1);
return 0;
```

Comment: Great thanks!But it only works with a negative offset like this 2012-08-20T15:00:00-07:00 and not positive offset like this 2012-08-20T15:00:00+07:00. Can we fix that?

Comment: Oops, I completely forgot how positive offsets were formatted. I thought that was the `Z`, but this actually means zero offset.

Answer (score -1):

If you always have the same format for your Date string you can simply use `.length` to check whether there was added something:

```
var your_string = "2012-08-20T15:00:00";
if(your_string.length > 19) {
    // offset added
    // offset = your_string.substring(19);
} else {
    // no offset added
}
```

Anyway, I would recommend to use `(new Date).getTime()` which returns the Milliseconds since 01.01.1970, 0:00:00h UTC. This is much easier to calculate with...